# Nest API returning 401 and 429 when using websock stream yet REST ok

Tags: android, firebase, http-status-code-401, nest-api

I have an android app that uses the Nest API. I used the NestLib from the sample app from Nest but updated the library with 1.1.1.

The whole API works great yet some accounts (not all) seem to come back with a 401 error (as well as a -999 on firebase debug) but only when initiating a websock stream (it authenticates ok then on redirect to stream the error appears). I tested this in POSTMAN whereby i can get all the data back using the Accept: text/event-stream header I get a 429 error.

From that i assumed it's had too many requests therefore I left it overnight and today its still doing the same. Strange thing is I can register that account to another clients in nest dev and it works and other accounts can still register to that client too and work ok.

Comment: Ho about some specifics? Also, what does the rest API say each of those return codes mean? Surely only one of them represents too many requests?